# Average Distance Between Random Points in a Rectangle

Tags: probability, geometry, euclidean-geometry, average, uniform-distribution

My question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195245/average-distance-between-random-points-on-a-line) but for rectangles instead of lines.

Suppose I have a rectangle with sides of length $L_w$ and $L_h$. What is the average distance between two uniformly-distributed random points inside the rectangle, and why?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22488/2970

Comment: In the excellent related  reference stats.stackexchange.com/q/22488/2970 @cardinal has not only calculated the average but also the distribution function of the distance. (+1)

Comment: For the similar problem in a circle with radius a I obtain for the average distance L between the two random points the expression $\text{<L>} = \frac{128 a}{45 \pi}$, and for the average of the square of the distance I get $\text{<L^2>} = a^2$

Comment: For the similar problem in the volume of the unit sphere I found for the $k$-th moment of the distance the following simple expression $<D^k>=\frac{72\ 2^k}{(k+3) (k+4) (k+6)}$

Comment: For the similar problem in the volume of the unit sphere I found, using Fourier transform of the moment generating function, for the PDF of the distance D the surprisingly simple expression $PDF(D) = \frac{3}{16} (D+4) (2-D)^2 D^2$. The problem of the statistics of the distance of two random points in the volume of the unit sphere should thereby be completely solved.

Comment: I have finally found a reference covering the problem for the n-dimensional ball published in 2018: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0004021.pdf. I'm happy to be able to confirm my findings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer, given in (Burgstaller and Pillichshammer 2009; Mathai et al. 1999), is

$$
\frac1{15}
\left(
\frac{L_w^3}{L_h^2}+\frac{L_h^3}{L_w^2}+d
\left(
3-\frac{L_w^2}{L_h^2}-\frac{L_h^2}{L_w^2}
\right)
+\frac52
\left(
\frac{L_h^2}{L_w}\log\frac{L_w+d}{L_h}+\frac{L_w^2}{L_h}\log\frac{L_h+d}{L_w}
\right)
\right)\;,
$$

where $d=\sqrt{L_w^2+L_h^2}$.

REFERENCES:

- Burgstaller, B. and Pillichshammer, F., "The average distance between two points", Bulletin of the Australian Mathematical Society, 80(3), pp.353-359, 2009.
- Mathai, A.M., Moschopoulos, P., Pederzoli, G., "Random points associated with Rectangles", Rendiconti del Circolo Matematico di Palermo, II, XLVIII (1999).

Comment: It seems to be a simple problem. But it's not. Good find. (+1)

Comment: The famous book "Integral geometry and geometric probability" of Santalo is available on line at (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183539854).