# Average distance between two random points in a square

Tags: probability, geometry, average

A square with side $a$ is given. What is the average distance between two uniformly-distributed random points inside the square?

For more general "rectangle" case, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208666/average-distance-between-random-points-in-a-rectangle). The proof found there is fairly complex, and I am looking for a simpler proof for this special case. I expect it could be significantly simpler.

See also ["line" case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195245/average-distance-between-random-points-on-a-line).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We just have to compute:
$$ I=\int_{[0,1]^4}\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}\,d\mu. \tag{1}$$
Assuming that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent random variables, uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, the pdf of their difference $\Delta X=X_1-X_2$ is given by:
$$ f_{\Delta X}(x) = \left(1-|x|\right)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}(x)\tag{2}$$
hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I &=& \iint_{[-1,1]^2}(1-|x|)(1-|y|)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy \\&=&4\iint_{[0,1]^2}xy\sqrt{(1-x)^2+(1-y)^2}\,dx\,dy\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$
that is tedious to compute but still possible; we have:

> $$ I = \frac{2+\sqrt{2}+5\operatorname{arcsinh}(1)}{15}=\frac{2+\sqrt{2}+5\log(1+\sqrt{2})}{15}=0.52140543316472\ldots$$
>
> ([OEIS A091505](http://oeis.org/A091505))

hence the average distance between two random points in $[0,a]^2$ is around the $52.14\%$ of $a$.

Comment: Does this variable $I$ have a name? I believe I have seen it before used as a named constant.

Comment: 3D version is called **Robbins constant**, not sure 2D version has a name.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins_constant