# What is the average distance of two points chosen uniformly on a unit square?

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the average distance of two points chosen uniformly on a unit square? What I am asking is how to calculate $E\left(\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}\right)$ for $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ spread uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Comment: intuitively, wouldn't it simply be 0?

Comment: @Ethan Zell Distance is always positive.

Comment: Chosen uniformly: the cdf of the distribution is $\text{cdf}(t)=t$ for $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: An answer is given here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypercubeLinePicking.html

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1294800/321264.

Answer (score 0):

Comments:

A brief simulation in R for a million points seems to
confirm the answer in the link (2 or 3 place accuracy):

```
 x1 = runif(m); x2 = runif(m)
 y1 = runif(m); y2 = runif(m)
 d = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)
 mean(d)
 ## 0.5215181
```

Can you start by getting the distribution of $(X_1 - X_2)^2,$
which seems to have expectation 1/6?