# How to find the average distance between two points in a square of length $1$ by using Average = sum of all distances / number of pair of points?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Lets consider a line of length $l$, let $X_1$ and $Y_1$ be two points and their distance from a common end point of the line be $x$ and $y$. Then, the distance between $X_1$ and $Y_1$ is $$ \vert x-y \vert$$Now I will consider a function  $$ f(x,y)=\vert x-y\vert$$ If I find the volume under the graph by the integral $$ \int_0^l \int_0^l \vert x-y \vert  dxdxy = \frac {l^3}{3}$$
My interpretation of this $\frac {l^3}{3} $ is that it is the sum of all possible lengths that can be marked by the two points $X_1$ and $Y_1$. Now, to find the number of points by which I mean the number of pairs of ($X_1,Y_1$) I find the base area of the graph $$\int_0^l\int_0^l dxdy = l^2$$ I think $l^2$ is the infinite sum of the number of points. Dividing these two also does give the correct result of the average distance between two points on a line $\frac l3$. $$ $$ My idea is to consider a line that is formed by two points on the perimeter the, the sum of all the distances that could be marked by two points will be $\frac {l^3}{3}$ so if I integrate this expression for the entire perimeter I would get all the possible distance that could be marked by two points on a square. For this I divide the perimeter into $6$ pairs, $2$ pairs of opposite sides and $4$ pairs of adjacent sides. [image]
$$ $$ Its fairly simple to arrive at the expression for their lengths. Now, I integrate $\frac {l^3}{3}$ for the perimeter
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 (x^2+y^2)^\frac 32dxdy= 0.20906$$
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 ((x-y)^2+1)^\frac 32dxdy= 0.42438$$ Now, similarly I integrate $l^2$ over the perimter to get the number of points
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 (x^2+y^2)dxdy= \frac 23$$
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 ((x-y)^2+1)dxdy= \frac 76$$
Now to calculate the average
$$ \frac {0.20906*4+0.42438*2}{\frac 23 *4+\frac 76 *2} =0.337 $$
I have described my entire process and I do  not know where I am wrong. The correct answer is close to 0.52. I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: As was pointed out to you before, see [Bertrand's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) for similar examples in which different probability distributions give different results for the same question.  To be sure, I have not looked carefully at your computation, but this is where I would start.

Comment: I did read the paradox but it didn't help me in identifying the problem.

Comment: @lulu flagging you to give you the opportunity to weigh in here.  I would have expressed it differently.  The OP (i.e. original poster) claimed: "My interpretation of this $\frac{l^3}{3}$ is that it is the sum of all possible lengths that can be marked by the two points X1 and Y1."  I don't regard that as valid, because you are not talking about a set with a finite number of elements.  So, you can't *count* them this way.

Comment: **To the OP**: If you have (for example) $10$ lines, and the total length of these lines is $(8)$ units, then you can deduce that the average length of these lines is $(0.8)$.  However, to the best of my knowledge, this type of analysis is only valid if the number of lines is finite.

Comment: @user2661923 Why? Also, is there a reason then why this works for just a line.

Comment: It is true that you can for example reason that since $\int_0^1 x^2 = (1/3)$, that the average height of $f(x) = x^2$ in this interval is $(1/3)$.  However, I don't think that this analogizes to what you were doing.  I could be mistaken.

Comment: For the line there is only one distribution under consideration.  On the square, there are two.  The uniform one (intended by the problem) and yours.  Now, a priori it is perfectly possible that these two coincide.  Intuition is hard to come by for these things.  But if you intend to substitute an alternate distribution you must prove that it coincides with the original one, else it is hardly surprising if the results are different.

Comment: @lulu How would I prove something like this ? And if I am considering every single point why is there any concern for a distribution? I have not studied probability this much so a book or anything else which could help ?

Comment: The fact that your computation yields a different answer might be a proof that the distributions are different (though, again, I have not checked your computation).  But, to start from scratch, take a possible open set that your two points might be in. It's easy to compute the probability that your points are in this set under the uniform distribution (it's just the normalized area of the set).  So compute it under yours.  See if that's what you get.

Comment: The lesson of Bertrand is that it is not a good idea to substitute some alternate version of a distribution.  Even if the alternate is sensible sounding.  Study the Bertrand examples...every method looks perfectly reasonable.  Even if the alternate is easier to compute with...you will still be forced to verify that the answer obtained through the alternate matches the one you were actually asked about.

Comment: @lulu I see what the lesson of Bertand is but what should I do now ?

Comment: I said.  Check directly whether or not your distribution matches.  Consider regions gathered near the corners vs regions in the middle of the sides, for instance.  Or, just do the computation using the obvious (strictly uniform) distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The average distance between two points in a unit square is

$ \overline{d} = \displaystyle \int_{x_1 = 0}^1 \int_{y_1 = 0 }^1 \int_{x_2 = 0 }^ 1 \int_{y_2 = 0}^1 \sqrt{ (x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 } d y_2 \ d  x_2 \ d y_1 \ d x_1 $