# Within a unit square, given n random uniform points, what is the average distance to the nearest k points?

Tags: calculus, probability, geometry, statistics

Within a unit square, given n random uniform points, what is the average distance to the nearest k points?  To be precise: if k=2 we are averaging the distances of the 1st and 2nd nearest neighbors to point i.

Here is a reference for the n=2 k=1 solution. 
[Average distance between two randomly chosen points in unit square (without calculus)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294800/average-distance-between-two-randomly-chosen-points-in-unit-square-without-calc)  (for this question I assume calculus is needed)

However, if you rather had **n** points and were interested in the average distance to the **k** nearest neighbors is this something that can be solved with an exact answer?

I have produced results empirically for 10,000 iterations:

n=2, k=1: 0.52

n=3, k=2: 0.52 <- intuitively identical to n=2,k=1

n=5, k=4: 0.52 <- intuitively identical to n=2,k=1

n=3, k=1: 0.39

n=5, k=1: 0.28

n=10, k=1: 0.18

n=10, k=2: 0.24

n=10, k=3: 0.28

n=100, k=5: 0.097

Comment: For a given point, you mean the $k$th nearest neighbor without the plural. Is that so ?

Comment: If k = 5 you would be return the average distance from all 5 nearest neighbors, not only the fifth nearest.

Comment: This interpretation should be explained in your question... because it is not at all evident...

Comment: When $n\gg k$, the distribution of points can be approximated by a [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) in the plane with density $n$. Then the number of other points in a ball of radius $r$ centered at a chosen point follows a Poisson distribution with rate parameter $\pi r^2n$. From this one could find the expected distance to the $i$th nearest neighbour, and thus, the expected average distance to the $k$ nearest neighbours, at least for the $n\gg k$ case.

Comment: I suppose the condition to avoid edge effects should be $\sqrt n\gg k$. In any case, for the $n=100,k=5$ case the Poisson process approximation gives $231/2560 \approx 0.0902$.

Answer (score 2):

Equation 12 in the [paper](https://www3.nd.edu/~mhaenggi/pubs/tvt09.pdf)

> Distance Distributions in Finite Uniformly Random Networks: Theory and
>   Applications

by Srinivasa and Haenggi, seems to answer your question:

[image: Equation 12]

Here is a simulation in MATLAB:

```
exps = 1000;
distances = zeros(exps,1);

N = 100;
k = 2;

for it=1:exps

    A = [ 2*(rand(5*N,1)-0.5) 2*(rand(5*N,1)-0.5)];
    A = A(sqrt(sum(A.^2,2)) <=1,:);
    A = A(1:N,:);

    B = [ 2*(rand(5*N,1)-0.5) 2*(rand(5*N,1)-0.5)];
    B = B(sqrt(sum(B.^2,2)) <=0.8,:); %There seems to be some problem on the edges
    B = B(1:N,:);


    [Idx,Dist] = knnsearch(A,B,'k',k);

   distances(it) =  mean(Dist(:,k));
end

experimental = mean(distances);

k = k;
analytic = (gamma(k + 0.5)/gamma(k))*( gamma(N + 1)/gamma(N + 1 + 0.5));

abs(experimental - analytic) # Gives 10^-4
```