# What is the relationship between mean seperation and number of dimensions for uniformly distributed points?

Tags: probability

If I have uniformly distributed points in an N-dimensional space with a range of 0 to L in each dimension what is the relationship between the mean euclidean separation and N?

I found [Average Distance Between Random Points on a Line Segment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195245/average-distance-between-random-points-on-a-line-segment) which is the 1D case and makes sense, but I am struggling to generalize to N dimensions.

I have plotted empirically results for L = 1.0 but it is not of a simple form to fit (at least not a form I tried). I do not have the reputation to post an image but this is the Python code to produce the chart.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import float32
from numpy.random import uniform
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from tqdm import trange

POPULATION = 100
MIN = 0.0
MAX = 1.0
DIMS = 2048

data = []
for d in trange(1, DIMS + 1, ascii=True):
    p = uniform(MIN, MAX, (POPULATION, d)).astype(float32)
    s = cdist(p, p, 'euclidean').sum() / (POPULATION * (POPULATION - 1))
    data.append(s)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, title='Mean Euclidean Distance between Uniformly Distributed Points')
ax.plot(data)
ax.set_xlabel('Number of Dimensions')
ax.set_ylabel('Mean Distance')
plt.show()
```

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976842/how-is-the-distance-of-two-random-points-in-a-unit-hypercube-distributed

Comment: That's what I need! Thx.