# Rules of Logarithms

Tags: calculus

I have come across the definition of a natural logarithm that says, $\ln x = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t} dt$.

Using this definition, I tried to prove a few rules. 'One' such rule is, $\ln x^r = r\ln x$, where $r$ is rational.( The nature of irrational numbers keeps us from the true value and this is why the rule does not apply to them, does it? )

Proof: $\frac{d}{dx} \ln x^r = \frac{r}{x} = r\frac{d}{dx} \ln x$

On taking the antiderivative we get, $\ln x^r= r\ln x + C$

For $x=1$, $C=0$.

This gives us $\ln x = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t} dt$. Now, $\frac{1}{t}$ is a continuous except at zero. This tells us that the integral function $\ln x$ is also continuous for $x>0$. The variable $x$ can take infinitely many values which are greater than zero. The rule above is true only for $x=1$. For $x=2$, we see that $C=\ln 2^r - \ln 2$. My calculator says that this difference is significant and that it cannot be ignored. Why are we not considering $C$ values for $x\neq 1$

Observation: I see that this procedure of making $C$ zero for a particular $x$ and then generalizing the rule is evident in the proofs of other rules.

Comment: This is not "the"  definition of logarithm but rather "a" definition of the logarithm function. I admit it is the easiest and most convenient one for establishing properties of logarithm. Also the rule you have mentioned holds for all real numbers $r$ provided you have a suitable definition of $x^{r} $ when $x$ is irrational. One such definition is given by $x^{r} =\exp(r\log x) $ which is based on the rule you are trying to prove.

Comment: And note that your proof does require $x=1$. You can't use any other value of $x$ to determine $C$.

Comment: You will find a lot of interesting stuff about the natural logarithm [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344993/unexpected-examples-of-natural-logarithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you had a mistake for $x=2$, instead it should be:

$$C=\ln 2^r - \color{red} r\cdot \ln 2=0$$

Thus no matter what $x$ you choose, $C=0$.

**EDIT**

To add a comment for the question: notice that by getting the integration result, we already know that $C$ is a constant that once fixed, would work for all values of valid $x$. Thus we could find $C$ by letting it fit for $x=1$ or $x=2$, or other values. But once we find the $C$ by fitting the value of one $x$, it is guaranteed it fits for all $x$.

And for a particular value of $x$, we could just calculate it, instead of using the rule you want to prove here.

Comment: Oh my! I realized that. But you see, we are trying to prove the rule here and while working out the constant, we are making use of the same rule. I find it a little confusing.

Comment: @R004 So by the indefinite integration, we know that $C$ is a constant that is not changing with $x$ we take

Comment: Now I realize. I made a very silly error with the constant. This helps.

Answer (score 2):

I finally thought to post an answer here which is an extension of my comments.

---

We are given the definition $$\log x=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{t}\tag{1}$$ for all $x>0$. An immediate consequence of this definition is $$\frac{d} {dx}\log x=\frac{1}{x}\tag{2}$$ You are supposed to prove that $$\log x^{r} =r\log x\tag{3}$$ for rational $r$ and positive $x$. Your approach can be made a bit more rigorous by considering the function $g(x) =\log x^{r} - r\log x$ for all $x>0$. Note that $g(1)=0$ and $$g'(x) =\frac{rx^{r-1}}{x^{r}}-\frac{r}{x}=0$$ and hence by a simple corollary of mean value theorem the function $g$ is constant for all $x>0$ and thus $g(x)=g(1)=0$. This completes the proof of the rule.

Note that in order to get the constant value of the function $g$ there is no other option but to use the value $g(1)$. You can use the value $g(2)$ or $g(3)$ but using that it will never be possible  to show that the constant value of $g$ is $0$.

Further the rule $(3)$ is valid for irrational values of $r$ also but it requires us to have a definition of the symbol $x^{r} $ for irrational $r$. One of the simplest approaches is to state that *by definition the rule $(3)$ holds for irrational values of $r$ also*. Thus we define $x^{r} =\exp(r\log x) $ for irrational $r$ where $\exp$ is the inverse of $\log $. In this approach the rule $(3)$ comes for free for all irrational values of $r$. You can choose any other definition of $x^{r} $ and based on that you can show that $(x^{r}) '=rx^{r-1}$ and then the proof of rule $(3)$ proceeds exactly as before.

Comment: This is excellent!

Comment: @R004 : If you are interested in the topic of logarithm and exponential functions then you can see their development via multiple approaches in my blog posts http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-1.html and http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html and http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-3.html

Answer (score 1):

In the formula  $\ln (x^r) =r\ln x +C$, the symbol $C$ is a constant. So regardless of which $x$ value you substitute you will get the same answer. We are simply picking the simplest one we can since $\ln(1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\ln\pars{x^{r}} & \equiv \int_{1}^{x^{\large r}}{\dd t \over t}
\,\,\,\stackrel{t\ =\ z^{\large r}}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{1}^{x}{r\,z^{r - 1}\,\dd z \over z^{r}} = r\int_{1}^{x}{\dd z \over z} = r\ln\pars{x}
\end{align}

Comment: Perfect use of the substitution $t=z^{r} $. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The straightforward way.