# Sufficient condition for a point in the plane to be accessible

Tags: geometry

Suppose $x_n$ is an infinite sequence of positive numbers less than or equal to $1$ (or perhaps a fixed positive real $r$), whose sum diverges to infinity. Let $P$ be a point in the real plane. We say $P$ is accessible according to $x_n$ iff  there is a finite sequence $P_0, P_1, ... , P_n$ such that $P_0$ is the origin, $P_n=P$, and the distance between $P_k$ and $P_{k+1}$ is $x_k$. Then, is every point in the plane accessible according to $x_n$, since we are assuming the sum diverges to infinity? It is certainly a necessary condition for every point to be accessible that the sum be infinite. I am asking whether it is sufficient also.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: As you are very used to this site, why don't you answer the question ? I have another question : could you say in which more precise context than given by tag "geometry" you are asked to answer this question ? Is it "Computational geometry" ?

Comment: If your divergent series is harmonic series, here is a connected issue: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2377994