# does it make sense to ask the expected value for discrete values ​in non-enumerable sets?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, sorting

I want to know, is this question well formulated? If so, what is the answer?

"Let randomly choose n numbers in a range [0,1], what is the expected value of the smallest number? if distribution function is uniform."

What is confusing me is "the probability of this event can be given by a distribution function"?
Please help me

Comment: It sounds like you have independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables $\{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n\}$, each uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, and you want to find $E[\min[X_1, ..., X_n]]$.

Comment: I think that's precisely it

Comment: Read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/195315/253273) and the comment.

Comment: In general, for mins and maxes you can use things like: $$\{\min[X_1, ..., X_n] > x\} = \{X_1>x\}\cap \{X_2>x\}\cap \cdots \cap \{X_n>x\}$$