# Probability function for distance to the nearest neighbour given $n$ points distributed randomly on a line?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, geometric-probability

*Note: I'm not familiar with a lot of mathematical terminology, so please excuse any misuses. I'd also make a request to use simpler language (if possible) in an answer*

What I'm seeking is similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931257/the-expected-distance-to-the-nearest-neighbor-when-n-points-are-placed-randomly) question, but instead of expected distance I'm looking for a probability function.

I'm potentially also looking for an equivalent within 2D space (line replaced with a circle of the line's diameter)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This Bot is stupid : your question is clear but there is a big issue in it : how do you define $n$ points distributed *uniformly* on a line ?

Comment: Is this your question: "Consider a fixed point $p$ on a given line (segment) and a set of $N$ points drawn uniformly at random from that line (segment)? What is the probability distribution of the distance of $p$ closest to it among those $N$ points?"

Comment: @sudeep5221 Unless I understand your interpretation incorrectly, then yes, that would be my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the problem as this: I draw a point at random uniformly inside the segment $[0,1]$. I draw another $n-1$ points (also uniform and independent). Let $D$ be the distance from our point to the nearest neighbour. Find the probability density of $D$.

$$P(D\ge d|X=x) = (  \max(x - d,0) + \max(1-x-d,0) )^{n-1}=\\
\left(\frac12 -d +\frac{|x-d|+|1-x-d|}{2}\right)^{n-1} \tag 1$$

Hence $$P(D\ge d) = \int_{0}^1 P(D\ge d|X=x) dx \tag 2$$

This is messy to evaluate. For large $n$, you can assume

$$P(D\ge d|X=x) \approx (1 -2d)^{n-1} = P(D\ge d) \tag 3$$

for $0<d<1/2$
Hence the probability density of the nearest distance is given by $$f_D(d) \approx 2(n-1) (1-2d)^{n-2} \tag 4$$

[image]

This gives an expected value of $E[D]=\frac{1}{ 2 n}$ (in agreement with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931257/the-expected-distance-to-the-nearest-neighbor-when-n-points-are-placed-randomly))

Comment: I'm not looking for expected distance, but a function describing probability of every possible distance.

Comment: You have that in the last equation

Comment: Hi, can you please explain a bit more how the CDF of $D$ given $X=x$ is computed ?

Comment: @leonbloy oh, I didn't realize that without the picture (unless it was there the entire time and I just didn't notice that it was loading). I had no idea that functions can have square brackets.

Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

If $x$ and $y$ are drawn independently from a UniformDistribution[0,1], the distribution of absolute distance $z = |x-y|$ is $p(z) = 2- 2z$:

[image]

The expected distance is $\int\limits_{z=0}^1 z (2 - 2 z)\ dz = 1/3$.